# “Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response” despite valid CORS config

Tags: javascript, python, cors

I created an API endpoint using Google Cloud Functions and am trying to call it from a JS fetch function.

I am running into errors that I am pretty sure are related to either CORS or the output format, but I'm not really sure what is going on. A few other SO questions are similar, and helped me realize I needed to remove the `mode: "no-cors"`. Most mention enabling CORS on the BE, so I added `response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` - which I learned of in [this article](https://medium.com/@fonseka.live/setting-cors-headers-in-google-cloud-functions-python-runtime-c6e589cc68ce) - to ensure CORS would be enabled... But I still get the "Failed to fetch" error.

The Full Errors (reproducible in the live demo linked below) are:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot add node 1 because a node with that id is
> already in the Store. (***This one is probably unrelated?***)
>
> Access to fetch at
> 'https://us-central1-stargazr-ncc-2893.cloudfunctions.net/nearest_csc?lat=37.75&lon=-122.5'
> from origin 'https://o2gxx.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>
> GET
> https://us-central1-stargazr-ncc-2893.cloudfunctions.net/nearest_csc?lat=37.75&lon=-122.5 net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

See Code Snippets below, please note where I used `<---- *** Message ***` to denote parts of the code that have recently changed, giving me one of those two errors.

**Front End Code:**

```
function getCSC() {
  let lat = 37.75;
  let lng = -122.5;

  fetch(
    `https://us-central1-stargazr-ncc-2893.cloudfunctions.net/nearest_csc?lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      // mode: "no-cors", <---- **Uncommenting this predictably gets rid of CORS error but returns a Opaque object which seems to have no data**
      headers: {
        // Accept: "application/json", <---- **Originally BE returned stringified json. Not sure if I should be returning it as something else or if this is still needed**
        Origin: "https://lget3.csb.app",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  )
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.json());
    });
}
```

**Back End Code:**

```
import json
import math
import os
import flask

def nearest_csc(request):
    """
    args: request object w/ args for lat/lon
    returns: String, either with json representation of nearest site information or an error message
    """

    lat = request.args.get('lat', type = float)
    lon = request.args.get('lon', type = float)

    # Get list of all csc site locations
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        nearby_csc = []

        # Removed from snippet for clarity:
        #    populate nearby_csc (list) with sites (dictionaries) as elems
        #    Determine which site is the closest, assigned to var 'closest_site'              

        # Grab site url and return site data if within 100 km
        if dist_km < 100:
            closest_site['dist_km'] = dist_km
            
            // return json.dumps(closest_site) <--- **Original return statement. Added 4 lines below in an attempt to get CORS set up, but did not seem to work**

            response = flask.jsonify(closest_site)
            response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST')
            return response

        return "No sites found within 100 km"
```

Fuller context for code snippets above:

- Here is a [Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nearest-csc-minimal-o2gxx?file=/src/App.js:114-698) of the above.
- Here is the [full BE code on GitHub](https://github.com/BGCastro89/nearest_csc/blob/master/main.py), minus the most recent attempt at adding CORS.
- The [API endpoint](https://us-central1-stargazr-ncc-2893.cloudfunctions.net/nearest_csc?lat=37.75&lon=-122.5).

I'm also wondering if it's possible that CodeSandbox does CORS in a weird way, but have had the same issue running it on `localhost:3000`, and of course in prod would have this on my own personal domain.

The Error would appear to be CORS-related ( `'https://o2gxx.csb.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`) but I thought adding `response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` would solve that. Do I need to change something else on the BE? On the FE?

**TLDR;**

I am getting the Errors  "Failed to fetch" and "field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" even after attempts to enable CORS on backend and add headers to FE. See the links above for live demo of code.

Comment: Don’t try to add access-control-allow-origin as a request header in frontend JavaScript code. And also don’t try to add the Origin header. Browsers don’t allow you to set that. So need to remove the entire `headers` block from your frontend fetch call, and try again — and then update the question with details what happens once you’ve removed that `headers` block.

Comment: It would appear that removing " Origin: "lget3.csb.app", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"" from the FE worked! Thanks.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to why it worked and what was wrong before. The FE is now the same as it was before I started looking up how to resolve CORS errors. But I also changed the BE so perhaps that is all that was needed?

 If you want to write up an answer explaining why I don't need the headers on the FE (as a lot of other answers suggest) and what IS needed on the BE, I would happily accept it!

Comment: OK, finally got around to writing up an actual answer.

Comment: Note that I also took the liberty of updating the question title — I did that in the interest of generalizing the description of the root problem so that future readers/searchers who run into the same problem can find the solution/answer here no matter more easily, no matter what particular combination of frontend and backend frameworks/libraries/runtimes they might be using (because the solution is agnostic to any particular technology choices.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Drop the part of your frontend code that adds a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Never add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header in your frontend code.

The only effect that’ll ever have is a negative one: it’ll cause browsers to do CORS preflight `OPTIONS` requests even in cases when the actual (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) request from your frontend code would otherwise not trigger a preflight. And then the preflight will fail with this message:

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

…that is, it’ll fail with that unless the server the request is being made to has been configured to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

But you never want `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response-header value. If that ends up making things work, you’re actually just fixing the wrong problem. Because the real fix is: never set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header.

Intuitively, it may seem logical to look at it as *“I’ve set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` both in the request and in the response, so that should be better than just having it in the response”* — but it’s actually worse than only setting it in the response (for the reasons described above).

So the bottom line: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is solely a response header, not a request header. You only ever want to set it in server-side response code, not frontend JavaScript code.

---

The code in the question was also trying to add an `Origin` header. You also never want to try to set that header in your frontend JavaScript code.

Unlike the case with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, `Origin` is  actually a request header — but it’s a special header that’s controlled completely by browsers, and browsers won’t ever allow your frontend JavaScript code to set it. So don’t ever try to.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve the same problem and I found a solution:

1. In my React app (running on port 5000):

   ```
   const bankApi = axios.create({
       baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
   })
   const resp = await bankApi.get('/users')
   ```
2. In my Express server (running on port 3000):

   ```
   const app: Application = express()

   app.use(express.json())
   app.use(
     cors({
       origin: ['http://localhost:5000'],
       methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
       allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
     })
   )

   app.use(function (req, res, next) {
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With')
     next()
   })
   ```