# How to fix CORS - same domain, Django API and React site

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, same-origin-policy, django-cors-headers

I have a page developed in React deployed with vercel, which makes requests to a Django web server. I've put them under my domain: one is page.example.com and the other is api.example.com. However, when the page makes requests to api.example.com I get a CORS error.

[image]

If i mouse over, the message in chrome is:

> cross origin resource sharing error: HeaderDisallowedByPreflightResponse

In the console, this is the error;

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/example_route/' from origin 'https://site.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

When I look at Azure web app, in the stream log, I only see the OPTIONS requests, not the GETs.

[image]

My settings look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'api.apps.ApiConfig',
'djoser',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
"rest_framework_api_key",
'oauth2_provider',
'drf_api_logger',  
'corsheaders',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [                                                                   
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',                     
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',                                 
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',                                 
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',                   
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',                      
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
'drf_api_logger.middleware.api_logger_middleware.APILoggerMiddleware'
```

]

I've tried

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

as well as

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["https://page.example.com"]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ("https://page.example.com')
```

, to no avail.

Comment: Because preflight requests are not authenticated, `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` should come first.

Comment: I've tried putting corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware on top of Middleware, but didn't solve.

Comment: What is the actual CORS error message? Add that to your question (as text, not as an image).

Comment: "cross origin resource sharing error header disallowed by preflight response"

Comment: Which header is disallowed? Rather than mousing over the problematic request, go to your browser's console to get the full error message. To fix the error, you'll  need to explicitly allow that request header in your server's CORS configuration.

Comment: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/example_route/' from origin 'https://site.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: You're doing it wrong on the client side. Drop that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the request; this is a response header, not a request header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should never add Access-Control-Allow-Origin as a request header in the frontend code.

Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response, therefore it will only give problems, unless the web server has been configured to send an Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

In short: it is only a response header, not a request one.

Reference: [“Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response” despite valid CORS config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62569594/request-header-field-access-control-allow-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-contr/62619667#62619667)